# dragInteraction itemsForBeginning is not triggered

Tags: ios, swift

I have xib file that contains two labels and I want these labels to become draggable. The problem is that itemsForBeginning function never fired! I am not sure what's missing in my code!

```
class EditSchduleLeftSide: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var collaboration: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var deepwork: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        addDragInteraction()
    }

    func addDragInteraction(){
        let interaction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: self)
        self.addInteraction(interaction)
    }
}

extension EditSchduleLeftSide: UIDragInteractionDelegate {

    func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let hitPoint = session.location(in: self)
        if let hittedLabel = hitTest(hitPoint, with: nil)  as? UILabel {
            let provider = NSItemProvider(object: hittedLabel.text as! NSString)
            let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: provider)
            return [dragItem]
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and i change your `addDragInteraction` method

```
func addDragInteraction(){
    let interaction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: self)
    interaction.isEnabled = true
    self.addInteraction(interaction)
}
```

Plus you need hold any label before dragging like long press.

Hope this is helpful

Full Code :

```
class TmpView: UIView {

class func instanceFromNib() -> TmpView {
    return UINib(nibName: "TmpView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! TmpView
}

@IBOutlet weak var collaboration: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var deepwork: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    collaboration.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    deepwork.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2
    addDragInteraction()
}

func addDragInteraction(){
    let interaction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: self)
    interaction.isEnabled = true
    self.addInteraction(interaction)
}
}

extension TmpView: UIDragInteractionDelegate {

func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let hitPoint = session.location(in: self)
    if let hittedLabel = hitTest(hitPoint, with: nil)  as? UILabel {
        let provider = NSItemProvider(object: hittedLabel.text! as NSString)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: provider)
        return [dragItem]
    }
    return []
}
}
```

**End Result of you code :**

[image]

Comment: can you please share the source code with me? because it still not working on my side

Comment: just replace above function in your code, then hold any one label for moment than try to drag. And make sure `isUserInteractionEnabled` for label.

Comment: Do not try to drag your `UIView`, try to drag `UILabel`, just hold on UILable for second .

Comment: again, not working.. I would appreciate it if you can share the whole project.. It would be helpful

Comment: Ok, I figured it the problem.. I set isUserInteractionEnabled = true for labels too. thanks